# change one element of an array into two and then delete the original (cell division simulation)

Tags: python, arrays

I want to simulate basic cell division using python arrays. I have u, which is an array of arrays as defined by:

```
n=2 #number of elements that can describe each cell
N=2 # number of cells
u=[np.zeros((n,n)) for i in range(N)]
V=2.0
epsilon=2.0
```

each u[i] represents a cell in the system and u is the entire system.
Next, I define some functions which I will use for my cell division algorithm later.

```
Mx=np.zeros((n,n))
My=np.zeros((n,n))

for x in range (n):
    Mx[x]=x-n/2

for y in range (n):
    My[y]=y-n/2
```

Here I am initializing my cells so they take values of either 1 or 0:

```
for i in range(N):
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            if (x-n/2)**2+(y-n/2)**2<5: u[i][x,y]=1
```

After I propagate my cell, I want to check for cells that have grown bigger than , let's say, volume V

```
   for i in range (N):
       if (np.sum([i]>V):     
          theta=random.uniform(0, 2*math.pi)
          u.append(np.zeros((n,n)))

          u[-1]=u[i]/2.0*   (1+np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My/epsilon))        
          u[i]=u[i]/2.0* (1-np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My)/epsilon))
          N+=1
```

Now I'm saying if my volume is bigger than a specific volume V, then I add a cell to the system (by appending an array of zeros) and I define my two daughter cells as

```
    u[-1]=u[i]/2.0*(1-np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My/epsilon))
```

and

```
    u[i]=u[i]/2.0*   (1+np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My/epsilon))
```

where new u[i] array replaces my original one. 
alternatively, I tried to append two np.zero((n,n)) arrays and defined my two daughter cells as

```
u[-1] and u[-2]
```

then deleting the original parent cell with

```
del u[i]
```

but that didn't work either. After I run this code, I am getting more arrays in u than I should be getting. If N=2, then I should have N=4 after cell division.

ideally I want my original u array to look something like this:

```
u=[array([[0,1], [1,0]]), array([[1,1],[1,0]])]
```

and I want to check if

```
np.sum(u[0])>V
```

then I will define two new components into u, namely

```
u[-1] and u[i]
```

where the new u[i] replaces the original u[i]

since

```
np.sum(u[0]) and np.sum(u[1]) are both > V
```

then my new u array should look similar to this:

```
u=[array([[1,1], [1,0]]), 
  array([[1,1], [1,0]]), 
  array([[1,1], [1,0]]),         
  array([[1,1], [1,0]])]
```

(these values in my array are simply example values. The real value depends on my function

```
  u[-1]=u[i]/2.0*(1+np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My/epsilon))        

  u[i]=u[i]/2.0*(1-    np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My)/epsilon))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that the code does not run.

What I think is not correct is:

`if (np.sum([i]>V):` to be modified, I guess as `if np.sum([i])>V:`

One bracket closure missing in:

```
u[-1]=u[i]/2.0*(1-np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My/epsilon)) 
u[i]=u[i]/2.0*(1+np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My/epsilon))
```

Missing values of V, and epsilon. At least V is required to understand the intended output shape.

Please write an example of the expected output shape in `u` to understand what you want to do. Maybe it is better with `n = 2` so the size of `u` is smaller.

UPDATE:
With the new information I think I understand the task better. Please check if the code below makes what you expect.

Check that `constant` is the correct equation.

Check that  `if (np.sum(u[i])>V):` is the correct statement.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random
n=2 #number of elements that can describe each cell
N=2 # number of cells
u=[np.zeros((n,n)) for i in range(N)]
V=2.0
epsilon=2.0

Mx=np.zeros((n,n))
My=np.zeros((n,n))

for x in range (n):
    Mx[x]=x-n/2

for y in range (n):
    My[y]=y-n/2

for i in range(N):
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            if (x-n/2)**2+(y-n/2)**2<5: u[i][x,y]=1
lenu = len(u)
for i in range (lenu):
    if (np.sum(u[i])>V):
        print(u[i], i, u, len(u))
        theta=random.uniform(0, 2*math.pi)
        constant = np.tanh((math.cos(theta)*Mx+math.sin(theta)*My)/epsilon)
        u_end = u[i]/2.0*(1 + constant)    
        u[i] = u[i]/2.0*(1 - constant)
        u.append(u_end)
        N+=1
```

Comment: I've updated my post, hopefully I made it clearer this time. V and epsilon are simply constants I can define let's give them values of 2.0 each.

Comment: Please tell me if my update is close to what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the issue, let's take some of the complexity out of it. NumPy and the exact condition for mitosis are irrelevant for how you replace one item in a sequence with two. Also irrelevant is how exactly those new elements would be created.

So let's assume our cells are represented by alphanumeric strings. The ones that are fully upper case are at the point they'd go into cell division. We can simulate the process as follows:

```
from itertools import chain

cells = ['a', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'e', 'F']  # Consonants grow quicker than vowels ;-)

# mitosis:
cells = list(
    chain.from_iterable(
        [
            '{}1'.format(cell.lower()),
            '{}2'.format(cell.lower()),
        ] if cell == cell.upper() else [cell] for cell in cells
    )
)
# Now, cells == ['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2', 'e', 'f1', 'f2']
```

(See [documentation for `itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). I'm feeding it a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions). Generator expressions work similar to [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but don't explicitly construct a list.)

We can make this more comprehensible by pulling out some functions:

```
from itertools import chain

def is_ready_for_mitosis(cell):
    return cell == cell.upper()

def perform_mitosis(cell):
    first_new_cell = '{}1'.format(cell.lower())
    second_new_cell = '{}2'.format(cell.lower())
    return first_new_cell, second_new_cell

def perform_mitosis_if_ready(cell):
    if is_ready_for_mitosis(cell):
        return perform_mitosis(cell)
    # (else)
    return (cell,)

cells = ['a', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'e', 'F']

# mitosis:
cells = list(chain.from_iterable(perform_mitosis_if_ready(cell) for cell in cells))
# Now, cells == ['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2', 'e', 'f1', 'f2']
```

Now all the simplifications I made are encapsulated in the first to functions. Thus, to use the third function and the `itertools`-based update procedure for your case, simply re-implement the first two functions as you see fit.